# How to speed up a large INSERT INTO SELECT in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, insert

I have a simple derived table query that I am trying to execute efficiently:

```sql
INSERT INTO derived_table
( userid , min_date , max_date)
    SELECT userid, MIN(service_date) as min_date, MAX(service_date) AS max_date
    FROM data_table
    GROUP BY userid
--  LIMIT 100000
;
```

The SELECT is reasonably fast, `data_table` has ~1 billion rows and is indexed by `userid` and `service_date`.

With `LIMIT 10000` the insert takes about 4s, with `LIMIT 100000` about 240s, and with no `LIMIT`... I didn't wait long enough to find out.

`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` is not an option because the `derived_table` is populated from many different data tables.

I think that I will have to chunk it, but I'm not sure what the best approach is. The best idea I could come up with was defining a cursor with the query and fetching forward by `n` lines and inserting within a loop, but I had difficulty coding it.

As requested by @a_horse_with_no_name here is the EXPLAIN:

```sql
EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, format text) 
SELECT userid, MIN(service_date) as min_date, MAX(service_date) AS max_date
    FROM data_table
    GROUP BY userid                                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=39493324.41..39504137.38 rows=41854 width=80) (actual time=268097.741..274785.386 rows=6042999 loops=1)
   Group Key: userid
   Buffers: shared hit=2460646 read=22955894, temp read=4585459 written=6307905
   I/O Timings: read=109033368.165
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=39493324.41..39503091.03 rows=83708 width=16) (actual time=268097.729..272192.388 rows=11506697 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=2460646 read=22955894, temp read=4585459 written=6307905
         I/O Timings: read=109033368.165
         ->  Sort  (cost=39492324.39..39492429.03 rows=41854 width=16) (actual time=267201.211..267826.062 rows=3835566 loops=3)
               Sort Key: userid
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 97656kB
               Buffers: shared hit=2460646 read=22955894, temp read=4585459 written=6307905
               I/O Timings: read=109033368.165
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 97448kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 97728kB
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=37079337.96..39489111.45 rows=41854 width=16) (actual time=163951.823..265136.847 rows=3835566 loops=3)
                     Group Key: userid
                     Batches: 261  Memory Usage: 4145kB  Disk Usage: 6163616kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=2460630 read=22955894, temp read=4509963 written=6232203
                     I/O Timings: read=109033368.165
                     Worker 0:  Batches: 261  Memory Usage: 4161kB  Disk Usage: 6131464kB
                     Worker 1:  Batches: 261  Memory Usage: 4161kB  Disk Usage: 6153240kB
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on data_table  (cost=0.00..27885239.47 rows=246717947 width=12) (actual time=0.011..109187.453 rows=197374360 loops=3)
                           Buffers: shared hit=2460630 read=22955894
                           I/O Timings: read=109033368.165
 Planning Time: 0.120 ms
 Execution Time: 276043.912 ms
(28 rows)
```

And the hash memory multiplier:

```
 SELECT setting, unit FROM pg_settings WHERE name IN ('work_mem', 'hash_mem_multiplier');
 setting | unit
---------+------
 1       |
 4096    | kB
(2 rows)
```

Postgres version is 14.3.

```
                                                   version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.3 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Comment: Have you looked at OS I/O stats while the insert is running? It’ll take a while to write the data+WAL for that many rows, plus index updates, triggers, etc. on the target table.

Comment: You mean server-side I/O? It's managed a managed AWS instance so I don't have root access. I'll check the console.

Comment: Is the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` actually faster?  If it is, that is an interesting data point, even if you can't actually do it that way in production.  Is the derived_table indexed at the time it is being populated?

Comment: Analyzing the execution plan of the SELECT statement itself would be helpful. Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for the SELECT part generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text) select ...` (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Plus your version of Postgres (obviously), and basic table and index definitions for `data_table`. Roughly how many distinct `userid`? Sufficient free space in your storage system? The result of `SELECT setting, unit FROM pg_settings WHERE name IN ('work_mem', 'hash_mem_multiplier')`? Is there any other table with distinct `userid`?

Comment: Performing the operation in chunks will not help, parallelization may. But without the required information we cannot help.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the clarifying questions: @ErwinBrandstetter : the data table has 56 columns and there are btree indexes on `userid` and `service_date` only. I'm fairly sure there's enough storage, it's AWS RDS. In this table ~6M distinct `userid` for ~1B records. There are other derived tables with distinct `userid` -- how is that useful?